# How to access swift package in Xcode extension target?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have created a swift package `CommonPackage` with files that are common to two targets. In my project I have two targets.

- MainApp
- Safari Extension target for MainApp

Now, I added this package in the Frameworks, Libraries section for both targets.
I am able to use this package in the main app target, but when I import this package in my `Safari Extension target` , it is giving me the

`No such module CommonPackage`  error.

The package file is pretty generic:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "CommonPackage",
    platforms: [
      .iOS(.v14)
    ],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "CommonPackage",
            targets: ["CommonPackage"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "CommonPackage",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "CommonPackage Tests",
            dependencies: ["CommonPackage"]),
    ]
)
```

Not sure why I am not able to use this package in the safari extension target.

Am I missing any key step ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my extension target CONFIG_BUILD_DIR is set to `build`, and when I change it to `$(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)`, I'm able to build successfully.